# Python no graba datos de sensores en archivo csv

Tags: python, csv, arduino

Estoy haciendo un tutorial de python con arduino,  con un ejercicio que trata de grabar los datos de dos sensores: un sensor de movimiento (entrada digital), y un sensor potenciometro (entrada analogica).

El problema que tengo es que si bien cuando ejecuto el programa crea el fichero .csv y los encabezados de la tabla (siendo estos que están definidos en el codigo), pero no graba los datos que  recogen los sensores.

Muestro el codigo que estoy empleando:

```
import csv
import pyfirmata
from time import sleep

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
board = pyfirmata.Arduino(port)

it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

pirPin = board.get_pin('d:11:i')
a0 = board.get_pin('a:1:i')

with open('SensorDataStore.csv', 'w') as f:

    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(["Number", "Potentiometer", "Motion sensor"])
    i = 1
    pirData = pirPin.read()
    potData = a0.read()
    while i < 25 :
        sleep(1)
        if pirData is not None:
            i += 1
            print (i)
            row = [i, potData, pirData]
            w.writerow(row)
    print "Done. CSV file is ready!"


board.exit()
```

El código realiza el bucle 25 veces pero no captura ninguna información de los sensores.

El sistema operativo que utilizo es un Ubuntu Studio 16.04. El fichero /dev/ttyACM0 tiene todos los permisos.

No he encontrado por la web nada que pueda ayudarme ni mis conocimientos en programación son suficientes para encontrar una alternativa.

[image: Al ejecutar el programa se realiza y imprime el contador pero los datos del sensor analógico no aparecen y los del digital solo en False]

Comment: ¿Si escribes `print(row)` te sale algo? Es decir, ¿`row` contiene datos?

Comment: ¿Te muestra en pantalla el valor de `i` (1,2,3...)? La obtención de las lecturas de los sensores las obtienes fuera del segundo bucle `while` por lo que no sé si se actualizan...

Comment: Hola @fedorqui, gracias por contestar . Si, me sale el resultado del contador de 'i' hasta 25, la notificacion que el archivo cvs esta listo y si le doy la orden print(row) m sale [25, None, false] o sea los sensores parece como si no recojieran datos. en el archivo csv me hace la tabla sin los datos del sensor analogico y el digital solo  'False'

Comment: kikocorreoso gracias por contestar. Solo hay un while, le añadido un print(row) al codigo y muestra lo que comentaba.

Comment: @kikocorreoso mira, Alphonsus te contestó (Alphonsus: usa `@` para que llegue notificación de tus mensajes).

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que en las variables `pirData, potData` tienes un par de listas con toda la información que necesitas, te recomiendo que uses **Pandas** para crear el archivo csv

```
import pandas as pd

# Creas el dataframe 
data = pd.DataFrame(
{'Potentiometer': potData, 
 'Motion sensor': pirData
})

# Puedes borrar cualquier fila donde el valor sea nulo
data.dropna(inplace=True)

# Reinicias el index para que cuente en orden los valores no nulos
df.reset_index(drop=True)

# Si quieres le cambias el nombre
df.index.name = 'Number'
```